# Searching correct Ingress definition for multiple services on different backends

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, ingress-nginx

I need help with setting up TLS termination (using ingress-nginx) for two services in different backends. Basically, the idea is to go with:

```
https://some.url.here/serviceOne/ -> http://hostOne/
https://some.url.here/serviceTwo/ -> http://hostTwo/someServiceNameHere/
```

I tried doing it with `rewrite-target: "/"`, `rewrite-target: "/$1"`, and `use-regexp: "true"`, but connecting to `http://hostTwo/someServiceNameHere/` constantly fails.

My ingress definition looks like this:

```
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: rp-some-url-here
  namespace: reverse-proxy
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    # ??? nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: "/$1"
    # ??? nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTP"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-ssl-verify: "false"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/upstream-vhost: "some.url.here"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-connect-timeout: "600"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: "600"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "600"
    # proxy-buffering is now disabled by default,
    # just having it here for reference
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-buffering: "off"
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - some.url.here
    secretName: my-tls-secret
  rules:
  - host: some-url-here
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: serviceOne
            port:
              number: 80
        # path: /serviceOne # using this with rewrite-target
        path: /serviceOne/.*
        pathType: Prefix
      - backend:
          service:
            name: serviceTwo
            port:
                number: 8180
        # path: /serviceTwo # using this with rewrite-target
        path: /serviceTwo/.*
        pathType: Prefix
```

Service definition is as simply as

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: service-one
  namespace: reverse-proxy
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: some.hostname.here
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: service-two
  namespace: reverse-proxy
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: another.hostname.here
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is a quick example of how it should be done ,also make sure that your second service responds to the port that you specified (8180)

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
  name: rewrite
  namespace: default
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: rewrite.bar.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /something(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: http-svc1
            port: 
              number: 80
      - path: /something2(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: http-svc2
            port: 
              number: 8180
```